# Why these are representations of ${\rm Spin}(D)$ and not ${\rm SO}(D)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, spin-geometry

In a course on supersymmetry I have learned the following way to construct spinor representations in $D$ dimensions: we first find matrices $\Gamma^A$ which obey the Clifford algebra $$\{\Gamma^A,\Gamma^B\}=2\delta^{AB}.$$

With these matrices in hand we define the new matrices $\Sigma^{AB}=\frac{1}{4}[\Gamma^A,\Gamma^B]$. We then verify that the $\Sigma^{AB}$ obey the Lie algebra of $\mathfrak{so}(D)$. Next to construct representations of the group one exponentiates the representation of the algebra, representing group elements as $\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta_{AB}\Sigma^{AB}\right)$.

Now, while Physicists often do not make such a distinction, I'm aware that when we try to exponentiate the spinor representations, we cannot obtain a representation of ${\rm SO}(D)$. Instead we obtain a representation of its universal cover ${\rm Spin}(D)$.

Now why is that? Why this cannot give us a representation of ${\rm SO}(D)$ but rather it gives us a representation of ${\rm Spin}(D)$? What goes wrong for ${\rm SO}(D)$ which does not go wrong for ${\rm Spin}(D)$?

Comment: You need the kernel of this representation to contain $\{\pm 1\}$ in order to pass it down to $SO(D)$.